# How do I fix a loose wooden tread on a concrete staircase?

Tags: concrete, wood, stairs

The wooden stair tread shown below has become loose when moisture entered the staircase from the wall's side and warped it. The water ingress has since been fixed, but the tread often makes a loud bang noise when somebody steps on it.  The staircase is made out of reinforced concrete on which the treads and risers are set. How can I fix it?

[image: Loose tread and riser on concrete staircase]

Comment: Sadly the tread is built into the wall appearing on the back. Breaking it loose would be a last resort.

Aligning the riser with the gap allows everything to fall nicely into place.

Answer (score 3):

The loud bang is presumably the groove under the step dropping rapidly back onto the tongue of the riser below it.

If you can get the tread to lay flat, by making sure the tongue in the riser enters the groove, and also if you can get the tread out without disturbing the rest of the staircase, then the simplest method would be to glue it down into the correct place.

Use sandbags &/or clamps [though it doesn't look too easy to get clamps on] to hold it in place until set.

If you can't get the tread out, then take out the next riser with it, trim one or both tongues a bit before slotting it back… absolute worst case scenario, you'll have to keep stripping back the entire staircase until you reach one end, but I don't think that's likely.

Comment: It looks like it might come out with some wriggling up and down, while pushing left (away from the wall).

Comment: Thank you! What parts do you recommend to glue? The tread with the riser or the tread with the concrete? Why do I need to get the tread out? Can't I just apply glue along the tread with a long thin stick?

Also, why should I trim the tongues?

Comment: Mainly I'd suggest gluing the tread to the concrete - but it will have to be clean & dust-free for that to work. You also need to check the wood hasn't warped & still fits properly, otherwise you may need to plane the underside. The trimming of the tongues is to more easily get the tread back in place. You could compromise & just glue wood to wood, front & back, but it's likely to still move that way.

Comment: I see, thanks! So glue is how the stair was originally held into place? What kind of glue should I use to join together wood with concrete?

Comment: You might discover what it was originally fastened with once you lift it. It may have just been gravity. Now, you'd probably want something with a bit of give in it, a contact perhaps, or a modern 'gorilla'-type expanding cyanoacrylate.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try @Tetsujin's solution first as that would be invisible when done, but if this still comes loose, you could consider drilling a few holes straight down into the standing board (as centerline and straight down as possible, you'll need grip on both sides) and drill a slight countersink. Then fix it in place with wood screws of sufficient length (at least twice the thickness of the step). You can cover the screwheads with some appropriately coloured wood filler when done.

As this tightens them together, the creaking should also stop. As an additional measure to both the gluing and screwing solutions, rub any surfaces where wood touches wood without being glued, with the back of a candlestick. This should remove any remaining creaks.

Comment: A good suggestion. Getting that hole drilled straight down into the thin wood of the riser is going to be difficult. It would _absolutely_ require predrilling (as you've recommended) to ensure the risers don't split from having the screw driven into them.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for elaborating :)

Comment: I was kind of avoiding that solution, but if you've a good SDS drill, rawlplugging it to the concrete would be "easier", with the same hide the screws issue.

Comment: Depends on the hardness of the concrete I suppose... Not everyone has a hammer drill handy (and a metal detector, assuming the stairs are reinforced with steel rebar). Also gonna have to insert some plugs into the concrete for grip, but yeah, when done, that'll be stronger and far less location critical than drilling wood :)

Comment: To clarify. One solution would be to screw together the tread with the riser with a few vertical screws. The other solution suggested by @Tetsujin in a comment involves screwing the tread onto the concrete base. I have a hammer (not SDS) drill, which seems to work on the concrete. Assuming that the treat can't be removed, to get the plugs into the concrete I'd need to drill a wide enough hole in the wood as well. This would then have the screw hold the tread only by its head, right?

Comment: I would say so, yes. Assuming the concrete is pretty thick (we can only see the side here), I would go for longer screws though, probably at least twice the thickness of the wood. But keep in mind the rebar thing, you'll need to use different drills for wood and concrete anyway, so start with the concrete first, then align the wood holes later (in case rebar is in the way).